# Calculate y derivative of image

Tags: c++, opencv, derivative

I want to implement the y derivative of an image.
Given is the following openCV function, who uses a Sobel Operator:

`Sobel(gray_input_picture, y_derivative_picture, CV_32FC1 , 0, 1, 3, BORDER_DEFAULT);`

There is an example how it looks like:

[image: result_i_want]

Now i need to implement it by myself without using this sobel function.

I found some help here: [Gradient direction computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003615/gradient-direction-computation)

What i now implemented was:

```
for(int x=0; x<gray_input_picture.rows; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<gray_input_picture.cols; y++)
    {
       if(x == gray_input_picture.rows-1 || x == 0)
       {
           y_derivative.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x,y);
       }
       else
       {
           Vec3b color;
           color[0] = gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x+1,y)[0] - gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x-1,y)[0];
           color[1] = gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x+1,y)[1] - gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x-1,y)[1];
           color[2] = gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x+1,y)[2] - gray_input_picture.at<Vec3b>(x-1,y)[2];
           y_derivative_picture.at<Vec3b>(x,y) = color;
       }
    }
}

bitwise_not ( y_derivative_picture, y_derivative_picture2 );
```

The x and y switch comes from openCV. That's why it's a little bit different. What i don't understand is, that i get a picture which i need to convert (black to white, white to black).

The Result is a little bit different too. It contains blue areas:

[image]

Anyone know how i can implement the y derivative better (that it looks similar to the Sobel function)?
Or does anyone know the problem in my implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I notice is you're subtracting unsigned chars.  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Also, assigning to a pixel the difference of pixel values above and below it is not really what Sobel does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would probably need to check out what Sobel operator does here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: I finally solved my problem with the help of this [site](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/03/gaussian-blurring-using-separable.html?m=0)