# Numerical gradient of a scalar vector in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, math, numerical-methods

Is there any way to calculate the numerical gradient of a scalar function in `C++`. `Matlab` has a nice function `Fx=gradient(y)`, which numerically estimates the gradient of a scalar function y. For example if `y` is a vector with the following scalar values:

```
y={30, 50, 13, 1, 4, 16, 19, 32, 54, 4, 23, 17, 33, 37, 6, 6, 11, 17, 5}

Fx=gradient(y)
```

along the `x` direction from `Matlab` gives:

```
Fx=[20,-8.5,-24.5,-4.5,7.5,7.5,8,17.5,-14,-15.5,6.5,5,10,   -13.5,-15.5,2.5,5.5,-3,-12]
```

Is there any way to perform the numerical gradient of a scalar function similarly in `C++`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003615/gradient-direction-computation

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have exactly the same output as matlab, use [central differences](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html#bvifdfu-5).

Pseudocode in C would be

```
for (int i=1;i<length-1;i++){
    g[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i-1])/2
}
```

You need to decide what to do with your boundaries (`g[0]` and `g[length-1]`)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to compute the coefficients of a cubic spline fit (uniform, natural), which convey first order derivative information. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html.

If the data is noisy, you can also consider the Stavisky-Golay filters for the first derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Tables_of_selected_convolution_coefficients

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an ambiguous question.

First it seems that you are asking if C++ has a gradient functions.  Not in the standard library as far as I know.  But you may be able to find open sources numerics libraries that do this.  I would look at the GNU Science Library GSL.

Second, why would you want to mimic MATLAB? As one of the answers points out it seems to be using the central difference formula but you could implement other schemes for estimating the derivatives.  And as other comments/answers state, you may need to consider what to do at the boundaries (though this is not necessary unless you are using this in a PDE solver).  In general, when you numerically differentiate discreetly sampled data you get fewer derivatives than data points.  Whether or not this is an issue depends on the application.

I noticed that you didn't state if the data was sampled for a uniform sampling of x, the independent variable.  This is important as all you are getting is the differences in data and not the actual gradient.  You will need to edit the pseudo code in the first answer by dividing by del_x = x[i+1]-x[i-1].  The matlab interface allows a step to be specified but you can make a more general function that estimates non-uniformly sampled data.